# Cannot cd into directory in AWS EC2 instance for another user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, shiny-server, rstudio-server

Not sure if this is the best place to post this question, if not then please point me in the correct direction.

Following these instructions - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/running-r-on-aws/ - I have successfully launched R, RStudio Server and Shiny Server on an AWS EC2 (Amazon Linux AMI) instance. When initializing the instance, I created a user and password by adding the lines of code in the user data, as the instructions suggest.

After ssh'ing into my instance, from my home directory, I have the following:

```
[ec2-user@ip-012-34-56-78 home]$ ls
ec2-user  johndoe  shiny
```

I am able to cd into the ec2-user directory, however when I try to cd into the johndoe directory, I receive the following error:

```
[ec2-user@ip-012-34-56-78 home]$ cd johndoe/
-bash: cd: johndoe/: Permission denied
```

Does anybody know how do I cd into this directory? The article I linked to does not mention it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `ec2-user` doesn't have permission on that directory.  So you have two (or maybe three) choices:

1. `sudo su -` to become root.  Then you'll be able to go into the directory and do as you see fit.
2. `sudo chmod 755 /home/johndoe` which will make that directory world readable.
3. If the `johndoe` user is a real user (i.e. has an entry in /etc/passwd) then you can `sudo su - johndoe` to become that operating system user.

The relative merits of the answers depend on the security that you want in your system.  If you just need to look then the first or third answer are likely the best as they are not a persistent change.  But if you really want to use that directory by the `ec2-user` then you may want to use the second answer.

Comment: Thank you. I am the sole user of this EC2 instance, and I made johndoe so that I could log into RStudio Server and code shiny apps. I don't want the rest of the world to be able to see or access the code I save in the johndoe folder. It sounds like the first answer should be sufficient for me, thanks!

Comment: Can I ask a follow up question - in my ec2-user directory is a ShinyApps directory, and within that directory are all of my different shiny applications. When I save my applications in RStudio Server, they are saved to home/johndoe/, and I am going to then move them to home/ec2-user/ShinyApps so that people can access the dashboards online. Is my code in home/ec2-user/ShinyApps secure?

Comment: @Canovice - I don't know quite enough about the environment to answer this correctly.  Could you post a new question so that someone who is likely more familiar with RStudio can answer?

Comment: exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved me. I am unable to connect to EC2 instance connect. So accessing my instance via session manager. Do I need to install all packages again if I want to run node apps that are in my ec2-user directory?

Comment: Hi @Nithur - it's likely you'll need to run `npm install` again but if that doesn't work post another question.

Comment: @stdunbar when I ran this command: `sudo su - ec2-user`, it wasn't necessary. everything was as they were.